# Why do my PyCharm inspections act as if legal Python 3.8 code is illegal?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.8

While attempting to update my PyCharm interpreter to Python 3.8(.1), I ran into a problem. While the code that used the new walrus (`:=`) operator executed properly, the code around it was highlighted as if it were illegal, as if it were Python 3.7 code. While researching a solution, I found that the following did not work.

- Restarting / Clearing the Cache
- Settings > Editor > Inspections > Python | Code compatibility inspection

  - Only version 3.8 is selected to no avail.

Why is my interpreter confused?
Here is the code if it is of any use:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
if (n := len(a)) > 10:
    print(f"List is too long ({n} elements, expected <= 10)")
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Pycharm?

Comment: The errors I get consist of unresolved reference, redundant parenthesis, the inspector acts as if the statement is illegal. However, the code does run, so it must be a discrepancy between the interpreter and inspector.

Comment: My attempts to update pycharm result in it getting stuck preparing patch files, I am currently at pycharm 1.3.

Comment: Pycharm 1.3? Do you mean 2019.1.3? The current version is 2019.3.1. The description of Pycharm 2019.3 states that it has "code assistance for all Python 3.8 features". If you have problems with the patch files you can do a complete reinstall.

Comment: Is there a nice way to reinstall pycharm?

Comment: Download and install. When I tried it, the setup detected the existing version and asked if it should use the settings from there.

Comment: I messed up and lost my settings :(. When I try and import them I get "Cannot find file C:\Users\me\.PyCharmCE2019.1\config\settings.zip". Can I fix this?

Comment: That's the moment when you realize that backups are a good thing. Is there any other PyCharm folder in C:\Users\me\ where old settings could be stored? If not - well, at least you didn't lose your code and the settings can be manually reconfigured in PyCharm.

Comment: At this point, I've restored enough that it will be fine. For some reason I can't remember what font I programmed in lol.

Comment: @SpaceGoat I would recommend setting your PyCharm to update automatically, so that this kind of issue does not happen again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you're using Pycharm 2019.1.3. You need to update to at least Pycharm 2019.3 to get support for all Python 3.8 features.